# How to show form this query in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two django models:

```
class RegistrationDetail(models.Model):

    registration_number = models.CharField(
        _("Registration Number"),
        max_length=32,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True)

    policies = models.ManyToManyField('Policy', blank=True)


class Policy(Models.model):
   policy_id = UUIDField(unique=True)    
   issue_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   start_date = models.DateField()
   expiry_date = models.DateField()
```

I have to form a query which finds out all the policies attached to respective registration numbers and then compares if the start dates of the corresponding policies of a particular registration number have a difference of 300 days or not. How do i proceed with this query ?

Comment: I think you need to make it a little bit more clear what you are looking for. Do you simply want a True/False if the spread of all related Policies is greater than 300?

Comment: I want a to return a queryset so that i can paginate it